# Manipulating SQLite database from Firefox Addon worker

Tags: sqlite, firefox-addon-sdk, xpcom, worker

I am developing a Firefox extension that needs to write to a SQLite database quite often (this is for some experimental purposes, not production or anything). The issue is that writing to the database has quite some overhead, so I thought that I could move this part to a background worker in order not to disrupt the browsing activities.

Now my issue is that I cannot access the XPCOM components from workers; namely doing

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
```

from the worker won't work (`Components` undefined).

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: How are you creating your workers?  If these are page workers you won't have access to the Components object.

Comment: @BryanClark I use [ChromeWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/ChromeWorker).

Answer (score 0):

See the indexed-db module https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/indexed-db.html

```
var { indexedDB } = require('indexed-db');

var request = indexedDB.open('MyDatabase');
request.onerror = function(event) {
  console.log("failure");
};
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  console.log("success");
};
```

Comment: If I take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB#Browser_compatibility), it seems that this solution is not compatible with workers.

Comment: you'd have to message to the main thread from the worker, the indesDB stuff is all async anyhow..